# Is there a better way to replace columns of one dataframe with those of another in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two dataframes, one is a subset of the other (but with different values).

```
iris
iris2 <- iris[1:2]
```

I want to replace columns of the first dataframe with the different values of the other

```
iris <- iris %>% mutate(Sepal.Length = iris2$Sepal.Length,
               Sepal.Width = iris2$Sepal.Width)
```

Is there a way to write this code more elegantly (eg with purrr)?

Comment: If there is a key column (or multiple) connecting one table to the other, use a join. `base::merge` or `dplyr::left_join`

Comment: I'm not sure what your example is intending to do, since iris already has the values of iris2, no?

Comment: Do both dataframes have the same number of rows/observations?

Comment: @JonSpring in the example given yes iris does have the columns of iris2. Though thats just an example. It seems that in the data OP has, the columns in one df are different from the columns in the other df

Comment: `df1[names(df2)] <- df2`

Comment: I also don’t quite understand your example, but [`dplyr::rows_update()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rows.html) may be helpful.

Comment: Multiple people are confused by your example, is this a better one?  `foo <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10); bar <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10)); foo %>% mutate(x = bar$x, y = bar$y)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon assumptions we can make about the two data.frames, different options are available. I'll call the original data.frame `df1` and the one you want to use to replace its columns `df2`.

Pick your poison! I like the base R solutions.

## df2 only contains columns to replace in df1

```r
# Example data
df1 <- data.frame(x = rep(1,2), y = rep(2,2), z = rep(3,2))
df2 <- data.frame(x = rep(4,2), y = rep(5,2))

# Base R
df1[, colnames(df2)] <- df2

# dplyr
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  select(-colnames(df2)) %>%
  cbind(df2)
```

## df2 contains additional columns

```
# data
df1 <- data.frame(x = rep(1,2), y = rep(2,2), z = rep(3,2))
df2 <- data.frame(x = rep(4,2), y = rep(5,2), w = rep(6,2))

# used for all answers
common <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2))

# base r
df1[ , common] <- df2[, common]

# dplyr1
df1[ , common] <- df2 %>%
                 select(all_of(common))

# dplyr2
df1 %>%
  select(-all_of(common)) %>%
  cbind(., df2 %>% select(all_of(common)))
 
# dplyr3
df1 %>%
  select(-all_of(common)) %>%
  cbind(., df2[ , common])
```